# why I can't set breakpoint at fopen in linux

Tags: linux, gdb

Here is my codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    fopen("./1.txt","r");
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

$g++ -g -o  m main.cpp

```
$gdb ./m
(gdb) b fopen
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804842c
(gdb) b printf
Breakpoint 2 at 0x804843c
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x0804842c <fopen@plt>
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x0804843c <printf@plt>
(gdb) r
```

it seems that the breakpoint at function fopen never work ,but at printf works fine.
why?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in GDB, which appears to be fixed in current CVS sources (as of 20120124).

The problem is that there are *two* versions of `fopen` in 32-bit `libc.so.6` on Linux, and GDB used to select the wrong one:

```
nm -D /lib32/libc.so.6 | grep '\<fopen\>'
0005d0c0 T fopen
00109750 T fopen

readelf -s  /lib32/libc.so.6 | egrep '0005d0c0|00109750'
181: 0005d0c0    50 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 fopen@@GLIBC_2.1
182: 00109750   136 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 fopen@GLIBC_2.0
679: 0005d0c0    50 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _IO_fopen@@GLIBC_2.1
680: 00109750   136 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _IO_fopen@GLIBC_2.0
```

If you also break on `main`, and repeat `info break`, you'll see that GDB set the breakpoint on `fopen@GLIBC_2.0`, but the function that is called is the `fopen@@GLIBC_2.1`.

Comment: FWIW, `gdb-7.4` has been released a few weeks ago.

Comment: Hi ,I have filed another question base on your answer , Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156414/why-lib32-libc-so-6-has-two-fopen-symbol-in-it